# Reference a Field in Content Type

Tags: entities, nodes

I created a content type with a text field in an Omega subtheme called "Prepaid" in Drupal 7. When a user inputs a hex value, it will create a div within the content area with inline CSS that changes the background color.  I know the PHP to make this work, but I am having issues determining where to place the function, where to call the function, and how to reference the field I created in the code. I am not new to coding, but I am new to coding within Drupal.  If anyone can help, I would be eternally grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Create `node--YOOR_TYPE_NAME.tpl.php` and `print_r($node)` object, find what you need and place it on write tag style

Answer (score 0):

It's happend with the help of preprocess function on the template.php. in drupal 7 themename_process_page(&$variables).use this function.

or you need to use default theme in drupal7[Bartik] . or Specific content type for create node--[content-type].tpl.php